# Conceptual problem about the theory of relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

Suppose a frame F is moving with a relative speed with respect to another frame S. Now, relative to a person in S, clock in F run slowly. Obviously then w.r.to person in F, clock in S run faster. But if we consider the case as in F, it is at rest and S is moving backward with same velocity. Then we conclude that clock in S run slower than that in F. Two contradictory result!!!

Can u please explain about it?

Comment: Try reading a book about relativity.  My personal favorite (at your level) is Merwin's "Space, Time and Relativity".

Comment: "Obviously then w.r.to person in F, clock in S run faster.". That's not even true in Newtonian physics, so why would it be true in relativity? Just because you start an imaginative but false statement with "Obviously" doesn't make it so.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not a contradictory result. Each observer sees the other's clock running more slowly. You're tacitly assuming the existence of a third, "absolute" frame wherein times of other frames can be unambiguously compared, which would be a contradiction because it would require duration measurements to be well ordered. However, one of the fundamental tenets of relativity is the nonexistence of any such preferred frame and thus the removal of any such contradiction.